# Creating one page Parallax style, cover background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have my background cover the page to create the parallax effect. Its the only thing missing as of now. Each "slide" div should cover the page. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxSLQ/) displaying the problem.

For my slides i am using the css styles:

> .slide {  background-attachment:fixed;    width:100%;     height:100%;
>     position: relative;     padding:30px;}

and the html

```
<div class='slide' id='slide1' data-slide='1' data-stellar-background-ratio='0.5'>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6 slide-1-logo'>
                <img src="img/MCP-LOGO-64x55.png" class='mainimg'>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-6'><h1> Welcome!</h1></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class='button' data-slide='2' title=''></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're .main class should have

> height: 100%.

for the content to stretch fully.